# How did companies like Nextly and StumbleUpon use iframes to show third party content, given that most credible websites block rendering in iframe?

Tags: html, iframe, web, stumbleupon

I want to use flight carriers website as iframe to validate user's PNR in my website.Could it be a problem to the flight carriers.

There is not enough written about this on web.
A link to some blog would be a great help

Comment: Interesting: the question title was copied from here http://www.quora.com/How-did-companies-like-Nextly-and-StumbleUpon-use-iframes-to-show-third-party-content-given-that-most-credible-websites-block-rendering-in-iframe?share where there's absolutely no other content besides the title.

Comment: Ya I picked it from Quora.I did not find any answer so I thought to ask it here.